# Theorems 6.11 and 6.13 from PMA Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

In the next page he applies this useful theorem:
[image]

For applying **theorem 6.11** our function must be also bounded but in **theorem 6.13** function $f\in\mathcal{R}(\alpha)$ and we have no information about boundedness.

Comment: What is $\mathcal R(\alpha)$?

Comment: This is the set of all function $f$ that has Stieltjes integral with respect to $\alpha$ over $[a,b]$

Comment: A function which is Stieljes integrable is bounded by definition.

Comment: Ohh right. Thank you. Sorry for my empty question

Comment: I do not understand the proof of b). How can we define $c=\pm 1$, plus, where did that last inequality come from?